# Setting a Property of an Object in Array 1 based on Value from Array 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, arrayofarrays

I have two arrays here. Array 1 is an array of arrays consisting of some objects as follows:

```
var house = [
  [
    { x: 50, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 150, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 250, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 350, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 450, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 550, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 650, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 750, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 850, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 950, y: 50, selected: false },
  ],
  [
    { x: 50, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 150, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 250, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 350, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 450, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 550, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 650, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 750, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 850, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 950, y: 130, selected: false },
  ]
]
```

And array 2 consisting of some boolean values

```
var isSelected = [
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false
]
```

How can I iterate over these arrays so that if the value of any element in array 2 is true, then I must set the value of the property "selected" of the object in the corresponding array in array 1 to true as well?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isSelected = [
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false
]

let  house = [
  [
    { x: 50, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 150, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 250, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 350, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 450, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 550, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 650, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 750, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 850, y: 50, selected: false },
    { x: 950, y: 50, selected: false },
  ],
  [
    { x: 50, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 150, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 250, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 350, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 450, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 550, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 650, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 750, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 850, y: 130, selected: false },
    { x: 950, y: 130, selected: false },
  ]
]

const res = []
house.forEach(el => 
  res.push(
    el.map(({selected, ...rest}, i) => ({ selected: isSelected[i], ...rest}))
))  


console.log(res)
```